# loop while data refreshes in excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops, wait, bloomberg

i am trying to create an innocuous loop while bloomberg refreshes a large amount of data. After the data refreshes I want that printed (not an issue).  The problem is, wait and other VBA delay commands actually stop the data from refreshing for some reason.  Seems like an issue w bloomberg.

I'm looking for a simple Do (something?) loop until a range is all numbers (isnumber).  I just need the program to keep running until all the data is updated so then it can print and move on.  Is there a simple do loop until a range is all numbers I could use?  Thanks

Comment: Is there a status that is returned from Bloomberg when it is finished?  Maybe you could just try a do loop n times with DoEvents. Vary n or check for a status?

Comment: There is no status or pop up when it finishes, i just need a loop to check that all the refreshing cells have actually returned data.  I'm a novice, so any examples would be great.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to refresh the data?

Comment: Application.Calculate
Application.Run "BLPLinkReset"
Application.Calculate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.StatusBar = "  Processing ticker " & arTickers(i) & " (ticker # " & i & " of " & nTickers & ")...waiting 20 seconds"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:20"))

Comment: wait does not work, it stops the link reset

Comment: Do
AllNumbers = True
Dim Data As Range
Set example = Data("AG3:Av200")
For Each c In Range(Data)
   If Not IsNumeric(c.Value2) And Len(Trim(c.Value2)) Then
       AllNumbers = False
   End If
Next c
Loop Until AllNumbers = True

Comment: Thanks Rodge, i think this is what I need, but I get an error on above, "object variable or with block variable not set. What did i miss?

Comment: http://www.vonixx.com/tips/tips34.htm

Comment: I will paypal someone $100 if they can fix this. Larry, your solution might be correct, but can't get it quite right.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options I know of,

One is to loop through each cell in the range, check if it's numeric, and if no, continue containing Do loop:

```
Do
AllNumbers = True
For each c in Range(Range of what you want to be all numbers, ideally dynamic named range)
   If Not IsNumeric(c.Value2) And Len(Trim(c.Value2)) Then
       AllNumbers = False
   End If
Next c
Loop Until AllNumbers = True
```

The other is to execute an Excel formula inside VBA like so:

```
Do
   ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="blahblahblah",RefersToR1C1:="=SUM(IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!R1C1:R9C2)),1,0))"
Loop Until Application.Evaluate("blahblahblah") = 0
ActiveWorkbook.Names("blahblahblah").Delete
```

Be careful though, both of these could create infinite loops if the Bloomberg data didn't ever retrieve or if it did but there was some non-numeric data in it.